Is there a way to swap my longbow from being a ranger for a shortbow?
I'm playing as a fairy ranger in the next game I'm in. I can't use a longbow because I'm a fairy, and therefore small. Can I trade it for a shortbow before the game starts?
That's pretty much all I need to know for now. Sorry if this is a duplicate.

Is it an organized play that has to strictly follow rules? Or is it a home game?

School club game. Gtg, won't have Internet for a while

It’s worth noting that you can use a Longbow, you’ll just have disadvantage. So you definitely don’t want to if you can avoid it. But if you are ever stuck with a Longbow, your character does know how to use one, and an attack with disadvantage is better than no attack at all.

@GuybrushMcKenzie Or, lean into it and seek out other sources of disadvantage that provide you some benefit.  Fighting while under darkness, fog cloud, or at long range helps keep you safe and your attacks can't get any worse than they already are.

What did your DM say?

@enkryptor school starts today, so I'll ask him when I get the chance, since he's a teacher here and I don't know where he lives.

@GuybrushMcKenzie really? I thought I just couldn't use them at all, and could only use shortbows

Just a detail for those unfamiliar: creatures that are Small in size can't use weapons with the Heavy key word. Longbows are Heavy.

Heavy  Creatures that are Small or Tiny have disadvantage on attack rolls with heavy weapons. A heavy weapon's size and bulk make it too large for a Small or Tiny creature to use effectively.

@Tasi yep! Check the rules in the equipment chapter for the Heavy weapon property. Or go here: https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dnd/basic-rules-2014/equipment#Weapons

Don't be lazy.  Set the bow on the ground, lift up the ends, nock the arrow with one hand, quickly grab the string with your free hand, bend over, step onto the grip, and then stand up, drawing the bow as you stretch yourself upright.  Then flap those wings, aim, and release.  You can do it!  Be careful not to let the string hit you in the back of the neck.

This is easy to solve, and you shouldn't have any problem making this work:

you receive equipment based on a combination of your class and background. Alternatively, you can start with a number of gold pieces based on your class... [table follows] (PHB p.143, "Starting Equipment," emphasis mine.)

At worst, you can just roll for gold and buy, among other things, a shortbow rather than a longbow. Downside: you might not end up with as much stuff as you would have had.
Better (hopeful) solution for you: take the standard starting equipment, sell the longbow, and buy a shortbow off the rack with the proceeds. The standard resale for undamaged weapons is half their list price (PHB p.144, "Selling Treasure"), a longbow lists at 50gp, a shortbow at 25gp, and Bob's your uncle. (A generous GM might let you "trade" your starting longbow for a shortbow and some gold, but maybe not all 25gp of the price difference.)

Related: Choosing equipment options at character creation

Also, re: "Downside: you might not end up with as much stuff as you would have had."  True, you could roll poorly - but this analysis shows that a ranger, on average, will roll 94% of the starting value of selected equipment, even if the equipment was selected for maximum value.  It's pretty good odds you will get enough for a shortbow and most other things you would want.
